# Old scifi book featuring krakens attacking humans

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

My memory of it is vague because I read it 30+ years ago. I believe it was published by Penguin. It's at least forty years old.

The basic plot:
Krakens from the deepest ocean come ashore and attack humans in a lengthy siege. They're almost invincible, except for their high internal pressure (having come from miles under the water).

Answer (score 14):

This would be [*The Kraken Wakes*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?333517) (1953) by John Wyndham.

[image: 1970-1980 Penguin cover of "The Kraken Wakes"]

Quoting from part of the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kraken_Wakes#Plot):

> The novel describes escalating phases of what appears to be an invasion of Earth by aliens
>
> In the first phase, objects from outer space land in the oceans. Mike and Phyllis happen to see five of the "fireballs" falling into the sea...
>
> Phase two of the war starts when ships all over the globe begin to be attacked by unknown weapons and are rapidly sunk, causing havoc to the world economy. Shortly after, the aliens also start "harvesting" the land by sending up biological "sea tanks", which capture humans from coastal settlements, for reasons that are never made clear; the Watsons witness one of these assaults on a Caribbean island.

A point of Stack Exchange etiquette: when posting a question, you’re supposed to indicate what research you’ve done. I recognized the book immediately from your description, having read it myself, but a Google search for "science fiction kraken" brought up the Wikipedia page for this book as the top result. I hope you enjoy rereading the book.

Comment: While it's useful to provide example Google searches that work for you, it's not always fair to chide other users for not finding the same things you do.  There are several other users here who habitually provide the Google search terms they use to solve story-id questions, but I frequently don't get the same results they do, based on my differing historical searches.

Comment: They were called Krakens in the John Wyndham book but they didn't match the classic Kraken (giant octopus thing) description. They were like armoured globes. Is the OP asking about big things with tentacles?

Comment: Thank you VERY much @Literalman!
I did search, and got a vast number of books with "kraken" in the title, but oddly, not this one.